# RGB color codes not showing color in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am using RGB color code for my bar to show in iphone app but they don't show any color i am getting these code values from photoshop but when i use them they don't show any color in iphone app

For first line i have RGB code from photoshop is 255.192,0

```
        color=[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:192 blue:0 alpha:0 ];
```

For Second line i have RGB code from photoshop is 195,214,155

```
        color=[UIColor colorWithRed:195 green:214 blue:155 alpha:0];
```

For Third line i have RGB code from photoshop is 49,133,156

```
        color=[UIColor colorWithRed:49 green:133 blue:156 alpha:0 ];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters of `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha` are floating point values between 0 and 1. So you have to divide all numbers by 255, e.g.:

```
color = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:0.75f blue:0f alpha:1f];
```

Comment: @james: I haven't seen that the alpha value was 0, i.e. the color was fully transparent. It has to be 1. I've changed my code accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting your alpha value as 1 like this `[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255 green:192/255 blue:0 alpha:1 ];'`

alpha is the transparency of your color

Comment: Values above 1 aren't valid values for this function.

Comment: Not just the alpha. Red, green and blue as well.

Comment: what are you trying to say Codo? **255/255** is **1**, **192/255** is **0.75**.

Comment: @Simon: For reference, **192/255** is **0**.  Without a decimal point in there somewhere, you end up doing integer math...and with integer division, only 255/255 would get you anything other than 0.

Answer (score 1):

RGB values on iOS only fall between 0 and 1, so you must divide the hue you want by `255.0f` like
this:

```
UIColor *color=[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:192.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.0f];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
color=[UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:192 blue:0 alpha:0 ];
```

to

```
color=[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255.0) green:(192/255.0) blue:0 alpha:0 ];
```

I dont know about the alpha but I believe it should be **1**